# Can spring boot actuator expose remote jvm metrics?

Tags: spring-boot, metrics, spring-boot-actuator, micrometer

For some old legacy customers,we want to expose some metrics for health monitoring.
Was looking at the spring boot application where it exposes lot of helpful metrics from local JVM.
Is it possible that if I install the sprint boot actuator application separately in the server, it exposes all these information from remote JVM?
Any other suggestion//alternative path is appreciated?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It’s not clear from your question whether the “legacy” app is a Spring Boot app. I don’t believe actuator works for non-Spring Boot apps, and it certainly doesn’t monitor an app remotely. Micrometer is fine, but you do need some setup in order for it to work that is usually done by Spring Boot auto configure (for instance, configure a GraphiteReporter).

If you don’t/can’t modify the source of the app you want to monitor, you can use the [OpenTelemetry Java agent](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation).

Comment: Fyi: As things look like now (2021-03-01), the target date for the OTel metrics **specification** going stable is end of this year. The implementation of the specification for the different languages (i.e.: java) will go stable some time after that.
"OTEL is going to release their first stable version soon." can be considered true (has already happened) for tracing but for metrics "soon" might be an overstatement.

Comment: @JonatanIvanov I should've been clearer. Thanks for the note, I've updated my answer.

Comment: To be honest, the cleanest thing here would be: "You can experiment with OTel metrics but do not use it in production.", let me quote an OTel commiter: "definitely don't expect users to have a good time if they use our alpha metrics": https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java/discussions/2328#discussioncomment-294992

Comment: @JonatanIvanov It all depends on your appetite for risk taking. alpha doesn't necessarily mean "it doesn't work, stay away", it means "don't blame us if things change and break your code or if there're bugs". I've used bleeding edge code in Prod more than once, and never had any repercussions. The key is to do the homework and understand what you're getting into.

Comment: I think calling out that OTel metrics is experimental, it won't be stable in the near future, and prod usage is definitely not recommended would be a fair message to the users.
I don't think this has anything to do with the fact how many times you have used bleeding edge code in prod.

Comment: You brought it up and I acknowledge it, there's nothing else to do. You're entitled to your opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Micrometer exposes JVM metrics about the JVM that is loading it.
If you want to expose metrics about an application, just add micrometer to it, you don't necessarily need spring-boot, e.g.: if your backend is prometheus: https://micrometer.io/docs/registry/prometheus
Pick the backend you want to use:https://micrometer.io/docs

Comment: You are right.I could have used micrometer .Only thing is customer doesnt intend to update the product.I am looking for a solution which doesnt need to update the main application

Comment: What do you mean by not updating it? If this is a spring-boot app you don't even need to add micrometer, it's already there, you just need to tell how to expose metrics (by default they are available at /actuator/metrics but you need to turn this endpoint on from config).

Comment: Application that I want to hook is a traditional xml based spring application. We cannot update the product so wanted to check if there are other solutions available without any change in the source code

Comment: To your question in the title: "Can spring boot actuator expose remote jvm metrics?"  the answer is yes.
But spring-boot-actuator is a spring-boot library, you need spring boot and add to your dependencies.
Also, if you want to add a feature that does not exist right now, you need to change something: configuration, classpath, java agent, spring xml config, code, etc. since you want to change the behavior.